# sorting 2D array with second column following the sorting algorithm of the first in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a [2,5000] array of strings that I want to sort just based on the first row, but I want second row to follow that sorting algorithm.

Can I get a lead idea on how I should be approaching this situation?

Edit:
My array looks like

{15, 13, 16, 19, 25, 29, 11}
{wed 12, thu 13, fri 14, sat 15, sun 16, mon 17}

and I want it as

{29, 25, 19, 16, 15, 13, 11}
{sun 16, sat 15, fri 14, wed 12, thu 13, mon 17}

Comment: What have you tried and also what do you mean first row and sorting algorithm? Can you please give us an example of the array?

Comment: Code examples would be helpful in knowing what you are wanting.  Give us a starting point.

Comment: theGlitch, How about posting *compilable* code?

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a two dimensional array; create a single dimensional array of some class that has two properties, and then sort *that* based on a custom comparer that only compares one of the values.

Comment: I already know this method but I'm not allowed to use classes. Is there an alternative way of solving this than using classes?

Comment: @theGlitch It's not that it's impossible to solve the problem without custom types, but it most certainly is the *best* solution.  Any other solution is almost certainly going to be worse.  It will be more work, more error prone, the code won't be nearly as clear, it will be harder to maintain, etc.  If you have a teacher that is not only encouraging, but *requiring* that you use one dimension of an array to represent a "type" instead of an *actual* type (namely, a class) then I'd run away from that class really fast, as that's an actively harmful concept to be encouraging.

Comment: I'm learning classes later in the course but this assignment clearly says to not create any classes.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is an assignment. You need to code a sorting algorithm (there are many, including some [very simple ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Simple_sorts)), and while sorting the first row, perform all the swaps on both the first and second row.

i.e. a sorting algorithm might look like

```
void Sort(string[] array) {
    // some logic to loop over the array, determine which elements to swap
        swap(array[x], array[y]);
}
```

basically you want to code something like

```
void Sort(string[] firstRow, string[] secondRow) {
    // some logic to loop over firstRow, determine which elements to swap
        swap(firstRow[x], firstRow[y]);
        swap(secondRow[x], secondRow[y]);
}
```